# Find values in column from column of data

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to search column K(Sheet1) for any matching data in column C(Sheet2). I have the below at the moment which works however I have 20 lines in
column C and don't really wanna repeat it multiple times. I can't seem to get it to search the entire range C6 to C25.

I have the following at the moment.

```
Sub LabelXXX

 LabelXXX       

   Sheets("new sheet").Select

     For Each r In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("K:K"))
          If r.Value Like Sheets("SYD").Range("C6") Then
             r.Offset(0, 1) = "TEST"
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: You're not specifying the range `C6 to C25` anywhere, why would you expect it to loop through that range?  (however you do refer to column K) Also what's with the double labelXXX?  (See  [mcve])

Comment: you can try to make a collection from each column then using the function from the following link https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/833646-vba-determine-if-item-part-collection.html then output the matches in a empty column or sheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
   For Each r In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("K:K"))


If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("SYD").Range("C6:c25"), r.Value) > 0 Then
             r.Offset(0, 1).Value = "TEST"
End If


Next r
```

i modify your code with worksheetfunction "countif" i will count if the value exists in the other sheet if it is found then its value will be greater than 0 meaning that the value exists in the other sheet.

i hope this helps

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your suggestion however

 If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("SYD").Range("C6:25"), r.Value) > 0 Then

is giving a run time error... I understand what you are trying to achieve but its just not working :S

Comment: Hi! i edited my answer. Missed the C besides the 25. I just tested it and it is working perfectly!

Comment: Thank you Elmen ! It works, shouldve caught that. Sorry 1 more thing - Do you know how I could include the contains * in the vba? As parts of text K will only be in C. Tried adding the * to the end of the cell of C and tried * in the VBA

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use `Find()` method of `Range` object specifying `xlPart` value for `LookAt` parameter :

```
Option Explicit

Sub LabelXXX()
    Dim r As Range
    With Sheets("new sheet") ' reference "new sheet" sheet
        For Each r In Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("K:K")) ' loop through referenced sheet K column range intersecting referenced sheet used range
            If Not Sheets("SYD").Range("C6:C25").Find(what:=r.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart) Is Nothing Then r.Offset(0, 1).Value = "TEST"
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you. 

Your formula works perfect however it the x1Part is not looking up part of the text? It seems to just whole with whole matching. Any ideas? Sorry i am new to this :S

Comment: I think I need something similar to a 'Like' or x1Part in the .UsedRange, .Range("K:K") as K will be the whole text and C6:C25 will be part texts...

Comment: XlPart is there to look for a partial match. I tested and it worked. What data are you dealing with?

Comment: Sorry - I probably didn't explain it very well. It is partial matching the other way around.

Essentially C column (SHEET2) has part of the text in K column (SHEET1) and if it matches i would like to places "TEXT" to the L column (offset 0,1). Your code works perfect but the partial match is the otherway around.

Comment: then just swap range addresses and change sheet names to corresponding actual ones.

Comment: Hi - I've tried that but the text offset is goes to the C column instead of the K...Is there away around that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this through a native formula like below:

In cell L2 assuming your data starts in row 2 insert following formula

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(K2,SYD!$C$6:$C$25,1,0)),"","TEST")`

and copy down as much you need.